# Is there any option to store a number as text with a specific format (comma as thousands separator and period as decimal separator) in Snowlake?

Tags: sql, format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Due to project requirements I need to **store a number as text**, since depending on a column I round it to some decimal places or others, and **with a specific format**: **comma as thousands separator and period as decimal separator**.

If for example I had to round to two digits and I have this 12500.987589 I would need to get this another 12,500.98.

The only solution I have found in **Snowflake** is something similar to this:

```
SELECT
    TO_VARCHAR(TO_NUMBER(TO_VARCHAR(ROUND(12500.987589 ,2)),'9,999,999.99',38,2))
FROM DUAL;
```

[image]

**Do you know any option to do this?**

Thank you very much and greetings,

Comment: Does the `SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_NUMBER(ROUND(12500.987589 ,2),38,2),'9,999,999.99')` produce desired result?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks @lukasz-szozda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to use the `round` function at all? You should be able to use

```sql
select to_varchar(12500.987589, '9,999,999.99')
```

this produces: `12,500.99`

Comment: I need the round because depending on another column I have to round the number to 0 , 1, 2 or 3 digits.

Comment: I've changed my code to TO_VARCHAR(ROUND(fact.actual_amount,maestro.num_decimals),'9,999,999.00') and now the format is correct. Thanks so much @simon-darr

Answer (score 0):

Number should be stored as number data type. **Formatting of the number is a matter of application layer**. Storing them as a text could lead to problems with implicit conversion, arithmetic operations, etc.

If that is not possible you could:

1. Create a view on top of a table that provides additional column with formatted string

   CREATE VIEW v_tab
   AS
   SELECT *, ... AS number_formatted
   FROM tab;
2. Create a computed column:

   ALTER TABLE tab
   ADD COLUMN number_formatted VARCHAR(100) AS (...);

The expression to get desired formatting:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_NUMBER(ROUND(12500.987589,2),38,2),'9,999,999.99')
```

Comment: Yes, I am clear that it is not the best option to store a numeric as text. But I already have in another column the number in correct format, and it is a requirement to have a column in text format for the visualization tool.

Comment: Then computed column could be a way. If the base column is updated, then formatted column does not need any maintenance as it is based on expression.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I don't know how to create that new column with the correct format. As I indicated in the question, using the "TO_VARCHAR (TO_NUMBER (TO_VARCHAR (ROUND (12500.987589, 2)), '9,999,999.99', 38,2))" I get the text without thousands separator.

Comment: @MarioRomeroRemírez Please check: [Numeric_format_models](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#numeric-format-models), a third optional parameter of `TO_VARCHAR`